# Scoping in Expressions c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm working with expressions and I have the following expression

```
//p=> 5 == p % 5
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p");
var e = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal,
        Expression.Constant(5),
             Expression.Modulo(
             p,
             Expression.Constant(5)
            ));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(e, Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p"));
var func = lambda.Compile();
```

I'm getting the current exception:

```
An unexpected exception type was thrown
Expected: System.NotImplementedException
 but was: System.InvalidOperationException : variable 'p' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Now this makes sense but what I find confusing is that when the Lambda expression is compiled does the Expression "compiler" keep reference of all variables in it's stack not the names?

Which means it could be possible to build a lambda expression

`(p,p)=>p % p == 5` 
where each p is different?
How is this information stored at runtime?

Comment: Yes, you binary expression keep reference to `p` variable and expects it to be available when you create the lambda. Passing different parameter with the same name will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, two parameters created with the same type and name are different.

Change the line

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(e, Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p"));
```

to

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(e, p);
```

Comment: So the names could be something like "p1" and "p2" obviously .Net will pick something more unique?

Comment: @dbarnes .Net won't rename the parameters; try it and find out what happens. In the expression tree the parameters are distinguished by reference. In the compiled byte code parameter names have no meaning.

Comment: I see that they are different references in the expression tree(haven't looked at the IL yet) but when it get's compiled does it do a lookup in the reference "table" to figure out exactly which one to use(this would make the most sense to me) and even mitigating the whole name idea in general?